# How to show passed props in "<Scene/>" "title" attribute in RNRF v4.0.6?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-router-flux

react-native-router-flux v4.0.6, how to show the passed props via 
`Actions.key({id:1})`
and want to display in header navbar
eg. `<Scene title={passedProps}>`

Answer (score 0):

Actions.key({title:'Header Title'})

Comment: Using above method only provide title in "key" component but not in the router.js where i written all scenes for routing.

Comment: I'm using redux to pass props to my router.js

Comment: instead of using redux, can i do that?

Comment: You don't need to pass props to Router you can change title from component. Please give more details why you need it ?
Also you can try <Scene title={Actions.refs.ScreenKey.functionName}>

Comment: like i want to show the particular user details on another screen with user name on header navbar

Comment: Im also showing username in navbar like this ; 
    componentDidMount() {
        Actions.refresh({ title: '@' + this.state.user.username });
    }